# Ident_Current returning NULL on SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server

The `ident_Current` function is returning a null on sql server 2005. After looking at some documentation it looks like it needs db_owner permissions to have visibility metadata, but thats only specified in documentation for sql server 2008.

Can someone confirm that its the same for sql server 2005?  I can't find any documentation to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use ident_current or any of the other functions to get the last identity, the user needs to have permissions to read meta data, so it needs db_onwer on that database.

Comment: Wait what? No it doesn't. It needs VIEW DEFINITION permission on the table object.

Comment: The `VIEW DEFINITION` permission pertains to the "source code" of an object and is part of the metadata, at least according to the MSDN page [Metadata Visibility Configuration (SQL Server 2008 R2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

[`IDENT_CURRENT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) will return null if the function is run under an account that does not have permissions to select the last id for a table or view.

Another thing to bear in mind when using [`IDENT_CURRENT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) is that the id returned can be for any scope and any session; this may be intentional on your part, but I usually use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) when I need to obtain an id for the last manipulated record

Comment: a user would have select permissions on a table by just having db_datareader permissions, but that is not working for ident current .

Comment: I agree, but I would advise just running GRANT SELECT on the table or view in question, just to be certain it is not this.

Comment: Is IDENT_CURRENT inside a sproc? If so, presumably the sproc runs under the user permissions in question?

Answer (score 0):

Russ is right. I want to point out that we had a developer use Ident_current to get the last identity and his proc ran at the same time as a dataimport and he got the identity of the record the import was running and this messed up the data integrity in the database as the child table was now related to the wrong record. It was a reall problem to find and fix, too. So be very careful using ident_current. In most cases scope_identity() is what you want.