# IDENT_CURRENT returns NULL

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Here in my code `DR.HasRows()` returns `True`, but `DR("LastID")` returns `DBNUll` while `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('SiteSection') AS 'LastID'` works in SQL Management Studio.

```
__SQLString= "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('SiteSection') AS 'LastID'"
Dim DR As SqlDataReader
ddConnect() 'It's my custom class that opens a connection to db, it works
DR = ddExecuteReader()
DR.Read()
If DR.HasRows() Then
    GetLastID = DR("LastID")
End If
```

Comment: Why on earth do you care what the highest ID is? What are you going to do with this information? I hope you're not going to add 1 to it and make assumptions that the new value will be the next one inserted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the account your .NET application is using does not have the same permissions as the account you are using to connect via Management Studio.

That said, I find your approach questionable at best. What are you planning to do with the information that comes from `IDENT_CURRENT()`? If you think that you can take that and make assumptions about what `IDENTITY` value is going to be generated for an `INSERT` that you have not performed yet, please think again. Several factors can invalidate that assumption - someone can reseed the identity in the meantime, or change the increment, or insert a bunch of rows.

So I suggest you reconsider what exactly you need to do and why you think `IDENT_CURRENT` is the way to do it. Based on your comment, you should be sending:

```
INSERT ... ; SELECT LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Now you can be sure that this is the ID you've inserted.

Comment: I do not want assume the next ID will be generated. after INSERT I want to redirect the page to the just created ID, page.asp?ID=blah.

Comment: @Maysam then SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); immediately *after* the insert.

Comment: What I got is that if use it in an independent function, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check this ..
[Ident_Current returning NULL on SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779337/ident-current-returning-null-on-sql-2005)

> to use ident_current or any of the other functions to get the last
>   identity, the user needs to have permissions to read meta data, so it
>   needs **db_onwer** on that database.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx):

> In SQL Server, a user can only view the metadata of securables that
>   the user owns or on which the user has been granted permission. This
>   means that metadata-emitting, built-in functions such as IDENT_CURRENT
>   may return NULL if the **user does not have any permission** on the
>   object.

You may find this interesting:

> When the IDENT_CURRENT value is NULL (because the table has never
>   contained rows or has been truncated), the IDENT_CURRENT function
>   returns the seed value.

Comment: @Maysam: are you using the same account when connecting via Mgmt Studio and in the program?

Comment: @Neoilsk Yes, it's the same account. But them run in the same machine

Comment: @Maysam: can you try with `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('SiteSection')` and `GetLastID = DR(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

In case it return null because no row inserted before use following code, it assume seed value is one :

```
     SELECT COALESCE((SELECT top(1) IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')),0) +1 as NextId
```